# Page thumbnail doesn't display on navigation

Tags: walker

I want to display thumbnail on navigation (using walker) but it doesn't display in the right place. Thumbnails displays only in index.php, before the navigation links and all these thumbnails are same.

```
class Footer_Navwalker extends Walker_Nav_Menu {

 function start_el(&$output, $item, $depth, $args) {
  $classes = empty ( $item->classes ) ? array () : (array) $item->classes;

  $class_names = join(
  ' ',
  apply_filters(
      'nav_menu_css_class',
      array_filter( $classes ),
      $item
    )
  );

  ! empty ( $class_names )
    and $class_names = ' class="'. esc_attr( $class_names ) .'"';

  $output .= "<li id='menu-item-$item->ID' $class_names><div class='col-lg-3'>";

  $attributes  = '';
  ! empty( $item->attr_title )
    and $attributes .= ' title="'  . esc_attr( $item->attr_title ) .'"';
  ! empty( $item->target )
    and $attributes .= ' target="' . esc_attr( $item->target     ) .'"';
  ! empty( $item->xfn )
    and $attributes .= ' rel="'    . esc_attr( $item->xfn        ) .'"';
  ! empty( $item->url )
    and $attributes .= ' href="'   . esc_attr( $item->url        ) .'"';

  $thumbnail = '';
  if( $id = has_post_thumbnail( (int)$item->object_id ) ) {
    $thumbnail = the_post_thumbnail( $id );
  }

  $title = apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID );

  $item_output = $args->before;
    $output .= "<a $attributes class='title'>";
    $output .= $args->link_before;
    $output .= $title;
    $output .= '</a> ';
    $output .= $args->link_after;
    $output .= $thumbnail->link_after;
    $output .= $args->after;
    $output .= '</div>';
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[`the_post_thumbnail()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post_thumbnail) `echo`s content. This is explicitly stated in the Codex, and the function name follows the WordPress convention (mostly) that function names starting with `the_` `echo` content.

> Display the Featured Image (previously called Post Thumbnails) for the
>   current post, as set in that post's edit screen.

The thumbnail will display as soon as that line in the walker executes. The thumbnail markup won't be concatenated into your string as it should be.

You need [`get_the_post_thumbnail()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_post_thumbnail) instead, which follows the WordPress convention that functions starting with `get_` `return` content. Many, but not all, `the_` functions have `get_` sibling functions.